How to replace the argument of the command that is already defined?
I use \textcolor in the color package to add some colors (red, blue, orange. etc) to the string.
For example, like this
This is \textcolor{red}{test}. 
This is \textcolor{blue}{test}. 

I would like to keep this command in the main text as is and make all these colors black by redefining the command in the preamble, etc.
I would like to do this with tex commands or macros, rather than replacement process by other programming languages or editors.
I tried the following renewcommand but it did not finish the tex process and did not give me any results, so I must be doing something wrong.
\renewcommand{\textcolor}[2]{\textcolor{black}{#2}}

Please let me know if there is a way to do this.

\usepackage[monochrome]{color}  defines all the color commands to not set colors.  Your suggested definition is an infinte loop defining \textcolor to expand to \textcolor repeatedly.

Note this is the same with the xcolor package. That is, \usepackage[monochrome]{xcolor}.

@azetina but why accept the additional overhead if you're not using colour?

I suppose the op wants to hide the color of a set of text and then disable it thereafter to show the color. Use case in English like teaching about verbs or nouns @cfr

@azetina - You may have misunderstood the intent of cfr's comment: Loading the xcolor package incurs a lot more overhead than loading the color package does. E.g., consider all the named colors that are set up if the options dvipsnames, svgnames, and x11names are specified. If all the extra stuff of the xcolor package isn't needed, it may be wise to just load color with the monochrome option...

@Mico I see, it does. The OP does not give enough info to offer viable options just stating the usage of color. Stating the xcolor package does not affect the desired result rather ascertains a possibility if they need to change to that pacakge.

Just a note: Your redefined \textcolor loops infinite because of the recursion. You should not define a command, that (unconditionally) expands to itself.Using \renewcommand*{\textcolor}[2]{#2} would work.

I would look at t from another angle. Give your colors semantic names. Then simply let the color to another. It is more flexible.

Thank you all.
@David Carlisle, @azetina, it workes for the article class file.
However, my actual class file contains \RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}, consequently I can't use your solutions.
I'm sorry for the lack of the information.
@cabohah's solution wokrks well for me. Thank you very much.

Why do you want black color instead of just not doing anything at all? \renewcommand\textcolor[2]{#2}

Thank you.
Just not doing anything at all is also OK. Your and
cabohah's solutions work well for me.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewCommandCopy{\oldtextcolor}{\textcolor} 

\newif\ifBlackInsteadOfColor
\RenewDocumentCommand{\textcolor}{omm}{%
  \ifBlackInsteadOfColor%
    \oldtextcolor{black}{#3}%
  \else%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
      \oldtextcolor{#2}{#3}%
    }{%
      \oldtextcolor[#1]{#2}{#3}%
    }%
  \fi%
}


\begin{document}

\BlackInsteadOfColorfalse

This is \textcolor{red}{test}. 

This is \textcolor{blue}{test}. 

\BlackInsteadOfColortrue

This is \textcolor{red}{test}. 

This is \textcolor{blue}{test}. 

\end{document}



Thank you very much.
It works for me.
I actually want to switch between coloring texts and making them all black for each compilation.
So I don't need the if sequence by \BlackInsteadOfColor in the main text.
I'm sorry for the lack of the information.

Your redefinition of \textcolor causes \textcolor to be a macro whose arguments are removed from the token stream and where as replacement text the tokens
\textcolor{1b11l11a11c11k11}2{1⟨tokens that form the second argument⟩}2
are inserted into the token stream.
This way in the stage of expansion you get an infinite loop of replacing
\textcolor{1b11l11a11c11k11}2{1⟨tokens that form the second argument⟩}2
by
\textcolor{1b11l11a11c11k11}2{1⟨tokens that form the second argument⟩}2.
Consider the comments of cabohah and David Carlisle and
yannisl.
Alternatively probably something like this does the trick:
% Uncomment the following line to switch coloring off altogether.
%\PassOptionsToPackage{monochrome}{xcolor}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifBlackInsteadOfColor
\newcommand\BlackCheck[1]{%
  \ifBlackInsteadOfColor\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {black}{#1}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\BlackInsteadOfColorfalse

This is \textcolor{\BlackCheck{red}}{test}. 

This is \textcolor{\BlackCheck{blue}}{test}. 

\BlackInsteadOfColortrue

This is \textcolor{\BlackCheck{red}}{test}. 

This is \textcolor{\BlackCheck{blue}}{test}. 

\end{document}



Thank you very much.
It works for me.
However, I actually don't want to change \textcolor{color}{text} command in the main text because I have already written them in many parts.
I want to do this by only adding commands or macros to the preamble, without changing the \textcolor in the main text , like the ljguo's solution.

@user6695701 You can place the command \PassOptionsToPackage{monochrome}{xcolor} right before \documentclass{...} for turning off coloring of whatsoever things in your document altogether. (I think David Carlisle already said this in a comment.) Consider whether modifying your document to have a bit more of semantic markup so that you can adjust visual appearance of things along semantics is worth the efforts in the long run. (I think egreg already said this in his answer.)

Thank you. I'll consider it.

When you type \textcolor{red}{test} you're giving some special emphasis to the word, aren't you?
Well, do yourself a favor and replace all occurrences of \textcolor{red} with \baz, all occurrences of \textcolor{blue} with \bez and so on.
You can obviously think of better names that carry the semantic of the situation.
Once you did the replacement, which should be easy if you wrote your document carefully, add something to the preamble:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\iftrue % or \iffalse
  \newcommand{\baz}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
  \newcommand{\bez}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
  \newcommand{\biz}[1]{\textcolor{pink}{#1}}
  \newcommand{\boz}[1]{\textcolor{yellow!20!green}{#1}}
\else
  \newcommand{\baz}[1]{#1}
  \newcommand{\bez}[1]{#1}
  \newcommand{\biz}[1]{#1}
  \newcommand{\boz}[1]{#1}
\fi

\begin{document}

This is \baz{test}.

This is \bez{test}.

This is \biz{test}.

This is \boz{test}.

\end{document}


If you change \iftrue into \iffalse and recompile you get

Your typescript will gain in shape and readability.
